# Conditions for a kernel of a bounded operator to be complemented

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I am well aware of the problem of complementing subspaces in Banach spaces as it was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114434/is-kernel-a-complemented-subspace) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108284/example-of-a-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space-which-is-not-complemented) .

Nevertheless, I wonder whether there are conditions for existence of a complement $M$ to the kernel $N$ of a bounded linear operator $T:V\to Q$. That is, under which conditions there is a closed subspace $M\subset V$ such that $N \oplus M = V$?

In my particular case, the operator $T\colon V \to Q$ fulfills these equivalent properties:

- $T'\colon Q' \to V'$ is an homeomorphism on its range
- $T'$ is injective and has a closed range
- $T$ is surjective
- <s>$T$ has a bounded right inverse</s> (I was wrong here, see comments below)

Any ideas?

Disclaimer: This relates to the [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392322/relation-of-the-kernels-of-one-bounded-operator-and-its-extension) I have posted the day before.

EDIT: I additionally assume that $V$ and $Q$ are reflexive and separable.

UPDATE: I have answered the questions, based on the comments.

Comment: The fourth bullet does not seem to be equivalent to the other ones (or do you talk about a bounded right inverse that is allowed to be non-linear?).

Comment: Notice that every closed subspace is the kernel of some map to another space, so our restriction to kernels is not very operative :-)

Comment: @Mariano Right. But, this means that if there were conditions for existence of complements, than they would be expressible in terms of properties of the operator.

Comment: @Martin . Not sure. I was using the map $T_f:V/N \to Q$ that is a bijection and concluded that, choosing the right representative of $[v]\in V/N$, $T_f^{-1}$ is the 'right' inverse to $T$. However, this 'right' is maybe not safe.

Comment: The problem is that $T_{f}^{-1} \colon Q \to V/N$, but you don't get from $V/N$ back up to $V$ with a *linear* map unless $N$ is complemented in $V$. In fact, if $T$ has a bounded and linear right inverse $R$ then $M = \ker{(1_V - RT)} = \operatorname{im} R$ is a complement of $N$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Can one of the commenters promote his comment to an answer? So that I can mark the question completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me summarize the comments and my findings to answer this question:

Having read through this [survey](http://m.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/kms_tex/986009.pdf) and some earlier papers, I have come the conclusion that the condition $T\colon V\to Q$ being bounded and surjective **does not imply** that $\ker T$ is complementable. Assume the contrary, then

- For any $N$ subspace of $V$, one can take $Q:= V/N$ and the natural surjection $T\colon V \to Q=V/N$ having $N$ as the kernel
- By boundedness of $T$ one has $V$ separable, then $Q$ separable
- As $Q$ is a quotient space of a reflexive Banach space, $Q$ is reflexive, cf. Palmer's [book](http://books.google.de/books?id=3k0lKh6QY-QC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=is%20a%20quotient%20space%20reflexive&source=bl&ots=vdJv9iI0ne&sig=h2Uas6VOj0QdLRNfRMpOzWrtVPk&hl=de&sa=X&ei=N6-XUbaDJcjTtQaHhIGgBg&sqi=2&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=is%20a%20quotient%20space%20reflexive&f=false) (pp. 79)
- and thus, one would have the contradictory outcome that every closed subset of a separable and reflexive B-space has a complement

This is equivalent to $V$ being isomorph to a Hilbert-space, cf. the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114434/is-kernel-a-complemented-subspace). And this is known to be not true for $L^p$ spaces, $p\neq2$, see this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1937-041-01/S0002-9947-1937-1501894-5/).