# Question about Hilbert Schmidt theory

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $V \subset H \subset V^*$ be a Gelfand triple with all spaces being Hilbert and separable.

Suppose $A:V \to V^*$ is such that 
$$\langle Au,u \rangle_{V^*,V} \geq C\lVert u \rVert^2_{V}$$
and $A$ is linear.

**Am I correct in saying that the eigenfunctions $\{\phi_j\}$ of $A$, by Hilbert-Schmidt theory, form an orthonormal basis of $H$, and an orthogonal basis of $V$?**

Let $V_n = \text{span}\{\phi_1, ..., \phi_n\}$. Now define $P_n:H \to V_n$ by 
$$(P_n u, v_n) = (u,v_n)\quad \text{for all $v_n \in V_n$}.$$

**Is $P_n:V \to V$ bounded? Clearly $P_n:H \to H$ is bounded but what about $V$?**

Thank you.

My confusion with the first question is that in Wikipedia the operator is a map $A:H \to H$ or $A:V \to V$. So I am not sure about my case where $A:V \to V^*$.

Comment: It is not obvious to me why you expect $A$ to be HS.

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks rather than an answer:

- $A$ may be only densely defined and unbounded, hence may not be Hilbert-Schmidt. But rather the *inverse* of $A$ is compact. Moreover, coercivity guaranttes that the inverse of $A$ is bounded, then you apply the H-S theorem. Think $A = -\Delta$ with $V = H^1_0$ and $H = L^2$. $-\Delta u = \lambda u$ means $(-\Delta)^{-1} u = \lambda^{-1} u$, and you are applying H-S on $(-\Delta)^{-1}$, not on $-\Delta$.
- $P_n: H\to V_n \subset V$ may be unbounded when $n\to \infty$, if we define the operator norm by $\|P_n\| := \sup_{v\in H}\|P_n v\|_V/\|v\|_{H}$. Please refer to my answer in: [Counterexample for the stability of orthogonal projections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433360/counterexample-for-the-stability-of-orthogonal-projections) . The divergence free Gelfand triple is often seen in the functional analysis theory for incompressible Navier-Stokes/Stokes equation.